# How can I show css active class using php?

Tags: php

Here is my site nav.php is look like :

```
<li <?php echo $active; ?>><a href="index">Home</a></li>
<li <?php echo $active; ?>><a href="report">Report</a></li>
<li <?php echo $active; ?>><a href="chart">Chart</a></li>
<li <?php echo $active; ?>><a href="export">Export</a></li>
```

and header.php page is look like :

```
<?php
$pageName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$explode    = explode('.', $pageName);
$title  = ucfirst($explode[0]);    

if($title == "Report") {
    $active     = 'class="active"';
} else {
    $active = '';
}
?>
```

I am using above code to show css `.active` class on currently view any page. but it's adding `.active` class to all pages.

Note : I have 4 pages. e.g: index, report, chart and export.

and My full page structure is like that :

In index.php page I am calling following page.

```
header.php
nav.php
js.php
footer.php
```

Comment: try to wrap everything in array, it will help you alot.

Comment: are you telling to use array of all pages and then use in_array() function ?

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594175/how-can-i-show-css-active-class-using-php/39594371#39594371

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping will give you additional flexibility over static content

```
$pageName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$explode    = explode('.', $pageName);
$title  = ucfirst($explode[0]);   
$nav = [
    'index' => 'Home',
    'report' => 'Report',
    'chart' => 'Chart',
    'export' => 'Export'
];

foreach ($nav as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li class="'.($key == $title ? 'active' : '').'>';
    echo '<a href="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>' ;
    echo '</li>'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");
```

and in your li

```
 <li  <?php if($activePage=="Report") { echo "class='active'"; } ?>><a href="index">Home</a></li></li>
```

Comment: exactly, currently you set $active to the same for every <li>

Comment: but I am using condition

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this:

```
<li class="<?= ('Home' == $title) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
    <a href="index">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="<?= ('Report' == $title) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
    <a href="report">Report</a>
</li>
<li class="<?= ('Chart' == $title) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
    <a href="chart">Chart</a>
</li>
<li class="<?= ('Export' == $title) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
    <a href="export">Export</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
$pages = array();
$pages["home.php"] = "Home";
$pages["report.php"] = "Report";
$pages["chart.php"] = "Chart";
$pages["export.php"] = "Export";

$active = "home.php";

<?php foreach($pages as $url=>$title):?>
  <li>
       <a <?php if($url === $active):?>class="active"<?php endif;?> href="<?php echo $url;?>">
         <?php echo $title;?>
      </a>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're defining `$active` only once and for all at the same time.

You probably should work with an array:

```
$navigation = array('index', 'report', 'chart', 'export);
```

And now you loop through that array, checking, which is active:

```
foreach($navigation as $n) {
    if(ucfirst($explode('.', $pageName) == $n) {
        echo '<li class="active"><a href="' . $n . '">' . ucfirst($n) . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $n . '">' . ucfirst($n) . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing the following

```
<li <?php echo ($pageName=="index.php")?" class='active'" :""; ?>><a href="index">Home</a></li>
<li <?php echo ($pageName=="report.php")?" class='active'" :""; ?>><a href="report">Report</a></li>
<li <?php echo ($pageName=="chart.php")?" class='active'" :""; ?>><a href="chart">Chart</a></li>
<li <?php echo ($pageName=="export.php")?" class='active'" :""; ?>><a href="export">Export</a></li>
```